# Why Netbeans clears line after carriage return?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hii people\rBye");
    }
}
```

The output of the above Java program should be `Bye people`. But it gives the output as `Bye` in the NetBeans. What is the reason for that?

Comment: How could the output be 'Bye people'? Care to explain the logic?

Comment: Thats what the \r does

Comment: Carriage returns 
–
Positions the 
beginning
of the current line. Do not advance to the next 
line. Any
characters
output after the carriage return overwrites the 
previous

Comment: But if you run the above java program using cmd or teminal it gives the output Bye people.

Comment: Funnily enough, on my eclipse IDE 'Bye people' is printed. Hmm, interesting.

Comment: When I do `System.out.print("Hii people\r"); Thread.sleep(2000); System.out.println("Bye");` in NetBeans, it also changes the behavior and prints `Hii peopleBye`. (I guess maybe the console does some kind of buffering and after the buffer is flushed the `\r` has no effect.)

Answer (score 2):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_Return#Computers. This might help. Carriage returns is represented differently on different platforms
 Although, the carriage return should actually mean returning the caret to the beginning of the line. It is represented differently on different platforms. It is commonly represented with a new line. Since it's the new line character for Mac. It also sometimes represented as just whitespace.