# same code with inputStreams: different responses in Eclipse and NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

The following code reads bytes from the standard input stream and displays them on the screen.

```
    byte[] data = new byte[20];
    int longitud = System.in.read(data);

    for(int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
           System.out.println(data[i]);
```

For example, if I type "abc" and hit Enter, it should return 97, 98, 99, 10 (LF) and 13 (CR).

If I run the application from the command line or from Eclipse it works correctly, but from NetBeans it does not print the code 13 corresponding to the CR.

Why? Thanks

Edit: NetBeans 11.1, Eclipse 2021-7, JDK 8 and proyects with Ant.

Comment: Update your question with the following information so that others can attempt to replicate your problem: [1] What type of project are you running?... Maven? Gradle? Ant? [2] Java version? [3] NetBeans version?

Answer (score 1):

> The output window is not a true console but is a logger that maintains
> the history. (The program output itself is only a part of the output
> which is intermixed with the output...
> [Source](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Carriage-Return-doesnt-have-same-effect-in-NetBeans-td2910391.html)

As mentioned in this forum the output terminal of NetBeans is not an actual console but formatted output. On the other hand Eclipse has an integrated terminal which is an actual command line console, hence the output.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085888/why-netbeans-clears-line-after-carriage-return) here, where the same problem was experienced in the output.

You can try configuring your NetBeans terminal by going to `Window->IDE Tools->Terminal`. Also you can install ***cygwin*** as mentioned [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/680/how-to-configure-an-integrated-terminal-command-prompt-in-netbeans-for-windows).